# How to "watch" a C++ dynamic array using gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, dynamic-arrays

Consider the following example:

```
int size = 10, *kk = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    kk[i] = i;
}

delete [] kk;
```

How can I add a watch for the whole array? I can add a watch one by one (*kk[0]*,*kk[1]*...), but since I know the array's length is there a way to do it automatically? I mean something like *kk[0..size-1]* or so.

I'm using NetBeans IDE together with cygwin g++ and gdb.

Comment: Employed Russian's edit changes the meaning of the question slightly, but the @<size> in an expression works for both display and print commands.

Comment: Do you want to watch it (break on read / write) or print it whenever GDB stops?

Comment: To watch (break) on the entire array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004374/watch-a-memory-range-in-gdb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `display *kk@<size>` From the doc for the print command:

> @ is a binary operator for treating consecutive data objects
>   anywhere in memory as an array.  FOO@NUM gives an array whose first
>   element is FOO, whose second element is stored in the space following
>   where FOO is stored, etc.  FOO must be an expression whose value
>   resides in memory.

Comment: I prefer to use p instead of "display", as it is easier to type. I've added it as a separate answer here.

Comment: "print" and "display" are not the same command. "display" sets a watch on a variable so you see it every time you get a prompt, assuming the variable is in scope.

Comment: @Matt, you're right. I didn't see that the question was about watching the variable. I have removed my misleading answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah, the editor of the question actually changed the meaning. I should probably change it back so I don't look like a buffoon.

Comment: @mkb, Don't you mean `display *kk@size`? Considering that `size` is the variable you want to use.

Comment: I actually meant to use the literal size of the array. I didn't realize that you could use a variable there. The doc I quoted implies that a literal is necessary. I didn't read the section in the GDB manual on Expressions before responding.