# how to use gdb to watch string in c

Tags: c, string, gdb, watch

As the toppic, I hope I can watch a string in c, for example below.
I hope I can only stop when
 HELLO->GOOD, GOOD->HELLO, I should I do?

`char s[10];` 

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

`strcpy(s,"GOOD");`

`strcpy(s,"GOOD");`

`strcpy(s,"GOOD");`

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

`strcpy(s,"HELLO");`

Answer (score 3):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651682/how-to-watch-a-c-dynamic-array-using-gdb) might help you.

I could not set a *watchpoint* (which would be the perfect solution) using that syntax, but the `display` command is a really nice alternative. It prints the result of its expression each time the execution is interrupted.

To make it work for your code, set a breakpoint at the `char s[10];` line and figure out the address of the `s` array (with `p s`). Then, set a display with `display *(char *)0x00000000@10` (where `0x00000000` is the address of the array and the number after `@` is the size of the array). Then you can set breakpoints at different points of your program so that each time you narrow the search space.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can set a watch for an expression

```
watch s[0]+s[1]+s[2]+s[3]
```

will stop when any of the first four characters in the string changes

Answer (score -2):

u can use gdb by compiling tha program with -g then create a break point and then by using n see debugging.....but use printf  statement often so that u can see what actually happens....